# How to set the same parameters for every required attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I'm making localization for my ASP MVC application and I want to set the same settings for every property.

for example:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredAttribute_ValidationError")]
    [Display(Name = "Hasło")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: just inherit the RequiredAttribute, too bad the DisplayAttribute is sealed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After creating CustomRequiredAttribute you should register your custom attribute in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CustomRequiredAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
    ...
```

source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1528277.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Override the `RequiredAttribute` and put your implementation details in the constructor i.e.

```
   public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute{
       public CustomRequiredAttribute():base(){
           ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources);
           ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredAttribute_ValidationError");
       }
   }
```

then decorate your property like:

```
[CustomRequired]
[Display(Name = "Hasło")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: To be more accurate. It does not work on client side. After submit normal required use javascript and show error. Custom required shows nothing. When send to server error shows up.

Comment: Did it work before?  If you are using ASP.NET MVC 1.0, data annotations won't work.  Attributes don't do anything by default except provide metadata for other application components to evaluate using reflection, so a RequiredAttribute doesn't do anything by default.  However, I assure you that if the RequiredAttribute "works", this will "work" as well.

Comment: It is new mvc 3 application. I also do not understand why your solution is not working on client side. Generated input does not have `data-val-required="My custom text".` Field with attribute like in my example works and generate `<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="My ." id="Password" name="Password" type="text" value="" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom attribute deriving from RequiredAttribute and setting those properties:

```
[MyRequired]
[Display(Name = "Hasło")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```